# Good advice regarding Mobile GIS Hardware and software for outdoor tasks?

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile, hardware-recommendations

Could anyone offer advice regarding outdoor mobile hardware and software for GPS-photos, data capture, and textual input. We don´t want to necessarily write long text, so the ability to write into shapefile format would be optimal. Obviously the price is a big factor and we have a budget of around 2-3,000 Euro/Dollar for everything. The colleague who needs this also has an iphone...so this could also be an option.

I know that this has been covered in some extent in other posts, but I also would like to know if anyone has used pure mobile GIS opensource software on Android or Apple based operating systems. The Ipad also has GPS build in and would also be a great platform for GIS mobile tasks.

Comment: What accuracy level are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used geopaparazzi (open source) on andriod with succes to map walking-trails.
http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/

Can log tracks or make georeferenced notes and pictures Using a json file you can make your own [geo note templates](http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/wiki/AddNoteByTag3#Supported_tags_%28via_the_example_form%29) (with drop-down's etc.)

You can export kmz (including pictures) or use their [Beegis](http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/wiki/GeopaparazziAndBeegis) tool to get the data in GIS.
I just used ogr to convert the KMZ to GIS-data.

Its not a pro-tool, accuracy is low, but is free.

Answer (score -1):

We have written a mobile geospatial data collection and audit app, that works on *any browser enabled device* (any device as long as it can enable GPS). That means any operating system that you might choose to use, as long as it has a browser.

If you are collecting points, you can use the app **free up to 100 points** (more if you ask nicely ;}) or you could just export each day's work and delete and start again (no bulk delete button at the moment though).

The app is called @Map and is found on the website [atmap.com.au](https://atmap.com.au). We use our own independent and unique recordset. It uses the GPS of the device or you could attach a GPS to your device (every device is different with its connection to GPS so I will offer no advice on setup).

The collection form is impossibly easy to set up. You define the table of the feature you want to collect and for each field, define whether it is text, number and whether a dropdown is  required. **You can specify new options in a dropdown as you collect.**

The form is automatically generated whenever you select a point. The form allows you to input whatever text, numbers, dates you require. No technical knowledge required, this app was developed for in-the-field operators with no IT special training.

After collection it is possible to export to kml or shape file, or you can leave the data on our server. We use GoogleMaps map images and Leaflet at the moment but as we are a startup, things are fluid.

Unfortunately we have to try to make money, so the professional version of points, lines and polygons will cost you and they are the ones that have that SaaS agreement, and can collect and store images using the device camera (so no extra camera needed, although you could store the external camera shot # in a field on the form and attach later to whatever GIS server you run).

These images are then stored on our database. We haven't enabled that feature for the free version. I estimate that with the professional version @ $75 AUD per month and 5 gB of server data (more if needed) you might be able to collect what you want.

I personally have an iPad (v2) and find it great collecting and using our app. The screen doesn't get too bothered with sunlight and, for me, is quite readable.

Disclaimer: I am its developer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] which leads to our [Help Center](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behaviour) that has a section on **Avoid overt self-promotion.** that is worth reviewing.  Having seen three answers by you this evening I can see that you are trying to tailor them to the questions but I think you are currently being perceived as falling on the wrong side of that guideline.  Don't forget that you can write all you like about your product on [your user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/66167/wallaby-tracks-software).